# Access the result of _; inside a modifier to change state machine common pattern

Tags: solidity

I'm implementing the State Machine for a specific case where the nextSate() depends on the execution of the method, as realistic State Machine. The code follows:

```
contract Transaction {
enum C_facts {
    Inital,
    Requested,
    Promissed, 
    Declined,
    Declared, 
    Accepted,
    Rejected
}
C_facts public c_fact = C_facts.Inital;
modifier atCFact(C_facts _c_fact) {
    require(
        c_fact == _c_fact,
        "Function cannot be called at this time."
    );
    _;
}
function nextCFact() internal {
    c_fact = C_facts(uint(c_fact) + 1);
}
modifier transitionNext()
{
    _;
    nextStage();
}
```

Now I want to apply the `transitionNext()` to a function that depending on its execution it is set for different states. Do you know how could I achieve this? I need a way to get the success or unsuccess of the execution at the `_;` of `transitionNext()` but I'm not sure how to do it...

Comment: I do not think Solidity modifiers supports this. I suggest use manual chaining of functions instead of modifiers. However I might be wrong as there might be some new features in recent Solidity versions to address this.

Comment: What exactly do you mean "depending on its execution"?

Comment: I'm doing these contracts for my master thesis. I have the Transaction contract from which all other contracts inherit. The idea is for all the other contracts to only have the business logic. When I say "depending on its execution", is if the function is successful meaning all the instruction, `require()`, and so on, can execute. Should I use `getTransactionReceipt(...).status` for this? @hrkrshnn